# Conjugate of a function involving *inf*

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, self-learning

For any two functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have $f\square g(x)=\underset{u\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\mathrm{inf}}\{f(u)+g(x-u)\}$. We need to show that for any two proper functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$, the property $(f\square g)^*=f^*+g^*$. Then, assuming $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty]$ is a convex function and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a real-valued convex function, we need to show that $f^*\square g^*=(f+g)^*$.

I started using the definition of the conjugate, namely that $f^*(y)=\underset{x}{\mathrm{sup}}\: x^Ty-f(x)$. Using this, we have that $$(f\square g)^*(y) = \underset{x}{\mathrm{sup}}\:\{ x^Ty-\underset{u}{\mathrm{inf}}\:\{ f(u)+g(x-u)\}\} = \underset{x}{\mathrm{sup}}\:\underset{u}{\mathrm{inf}}\:\{ x^Ty-f(u)-g(x-u)\}.$$

However, my problem is: how can I set this equal to $f^*+g^*$ if this last equation does not involve $u$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints:

1. For $X\subset\mathbb{R}$, we have $-\textrm{inf}(X) =\mathbf{\sup}(-X)$ (not $\inf(-X)$, as currently stated).
2. Let's also note that
   $$x^\top y - f(u) - g(x-u) = \big[(x-u)^\top y - g(x-u)\big] + \big[u^\top y - f(u)\big].$$
   Can we use a change-of-variables to have both bracketed terms look like conjugates?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could that change of variable be $x-u=\frac{x}{2}$, so $u=\frac{x}{2}$? I feel like this is not correct because it is assigning a value to $u$, but then how can I make $x-u$ equal to $u$?

Comment: Luckily, due to the first hint, we have two suprema, and suprema can commute, i.e., $\sup_{x} \sup_{u} (X) = \sup_{u}\sup_{x}(X)$. If we hold the $u$ terms fixed, and only consider the terms which have an $x$, then we can evaluate the supremum over the $x$. Therefore, we can just use a change of variables $z=x-u$ and you'll end up with $\sup_{x} (x-u)^\top y-g(x-u)=\sup_{z} z^\top y-g(z)=g^*(y)$. After that, you can evaluate the $\sup_{u}$ bit and it should yield the result.